# Prey predator model via polar coordinate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the predator prey model,

$$x'=ax-bxy$$

$$y'=cxy − dy$$

Which has the equilibrium point $(d/c,a/b).$ Transform this equilibrium to the origin and compute $G$ where $\displaystyle G=\int_0^{2\pi} g(\theta) d\theta,$ where $g(\theta)=\frac{dr}{r}.$

My solution:

By the polor coordinates, $x=r \cos(\theta)$, $y=r \sin(\theta)$. Define $z=x-d/c$, $w=y-a/b$ $\Rightarrow$, $$z'=x'=a(z+d/c)-b([z+d/c][w+a/b])$$
$$ \Rightarrow z'=-bzw-w \frac{db}{c}.$$
Similarly, $w'=czw+z \frac{ac}{b}.$ Than by the polor coordinate, we have $$z'=-b(r^2 sin \theta \cos \theta-(a/b) r \cos \theta -(d/c) r \sin \theta +\frac{ad}{cb})-\frac{db}{c}r \sin \theta -\frac{da}{c}$$
similarly for $w'$. I am getting stuck here, because I could not find the function $g(\theta)$ to compute the integral, I am not sure if my transforming for the equliprium point is correct or not. I reaally apprecitate any help or hint.

Comment: Notations are misleading, due to the use of $d$ for integration and as a parameter. You may find [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations) and enclosed references interesting